# Jenkins unable to launch actual chrome browser from selenium script

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to lunch chrome browser when I am running script through Jenkins,
If I build the job then i can see the execution of Job in Jenkins console but actual browser is not launching, I am not running script in headless browser.
I want to launch the actual browser because in my suite, I am having file upload scenario.
i am using Jenkins as a service.
I am running it plan, not on salve.

To Run the Job we are using 'mvn test' in 'windows batch command' option.
Details:
OS: windows server 2012 stranded

Jenkins version: 2.190

java = 8.0

chrome version : 79.0.3945.88

Selenium = 3 (Cucumber)

Can any one help me on this.
Thanks

Comment: Give more details: job definition, tests, etc..

Comment: for running job we are using 'mvn test' in windows batch command option , we are using selenium 3 java

Comment: also we are written scripts in cucumber framework using pom.xml we are executing it

Comment: Have to successfully run the script without using jenkins?

Comment: Yes,I have run the script through eclipse then it is launching browser, also i am able to run the script through command prompt by using 'mvn test'

Comment: Jenkins as a service launch browser in headless mode. I would suggest you to run it as a war.

Comment: @Tanuj-> we can't launch it as .war because development project are already running on it.

Comment: it might help you :: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4963/jenkins-executes-selenium-test-in-headless-mode-while-use-jenkins-as-service . But I suggest you install a slave on the machine and run your test.